# Accessing cell values from a an asp.net c# DataTable to a string to then store in the sessions Vars

Tags: c#, sql

What want to achieve: I am trying to collect a single row of data from a sql stored procedure and place it to a `DataTable` from within a class on a separate cs file in my project.

Then return it (as a DataTable object to the calling code on another part(cs page) of the project.

Then i wish to get the cell value of each column in that row from said `DataTable` and convert it to a `string` that is going to become a `session variable`.

For some reason which i don't understand (im still cutting my teeth in coding), i cannot get to the Cell values as i would expect. When i check them in `VS2010` '`Locals`' tab, i see that the data expected has pulled across to  "dtDerverVars >Rows > Non-Public Members > Results View > [0] > ItemArray", i can see the values expected there.

But using the common method of retrieving cell data, that i have found countless examples of on tinternet eg:

```
DataTable Dt = GetUserDetails(); 
string username = Dt.Rows[0]["username"].ToString();
```

Does not seem to work as expected.

please see the code im trying to use stored in a separate cs file in a public class '`clCommonFunctions`':

```
public static DataTable TryAutoLogin(string strREMOTE_USER)
{
    SqlConnection siConnection = new SqlConnection();
    siConnection.ConnectionString = Databases.getDbConnectionString("csSharedInfo");
    siConnection.Open();
    SqlCommand seCmd = new SqlCommand("GetSignOnDetails", siConnection);
    seCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    seCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DomainAccount", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 300));
    seCmd.Parameters["@DomainAccount"].Value = strREMOTE_USER;
    seCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
    seCmd.Connection = siConnection;
    sda.SelectCommand = seCmd;
    DataTable dtServerVars = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dtServerVars);
    siConnection.Close();
    if (dtServerVars != null)
    {
        if (dtServerVars.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        return dtServerVars;
    }
}
    return null;
}
```

And this is the calling code from a cs page called 'Site Master.cs' in the same project:

```
DataTable dtServerVars = clCommonFunctions.TryAutoLogin("europe\\MrTest");

Session["CablingUserID"]= dtServerVars.Rows[0]["CablingUserID"].ToString();
Session["CablingUseremail"] = dtServerVars.Rows[0]["CablingUseremail"].ToString();
Session["CablingLogin"] = dtServerVars.Rows[0]["CablingLogin"].ToString();
Session["CablingPassword"] = dtServerVars.Rows[0]["CablingPassword"].ToString();
Session["CablingPersonnel"] = dtServerVars.Rows[0]["CablingPersonnel"].ToString();
Session["CablingSurname"] = dtServerVars.Rows[0]["CablingSurname"].ToString();
Session["CablingFirstName"] = dtServerVars.Rows[0]["CablingFirstName"].ToString();
Session["CablingSuperUser"] = dtServerVars.Rows[0]["CablingSuperUser"].ToString();
Session["CablingDateAdded"] = dtServerVars.Rows[0]["CablingDateAdded"].ToString();
Session["CablingContact"] = dtServerVars.Rows[0]["CablingContact"].ToString();
Session["CablingApprovalAuthority"] = dtServerVars.Rows[0]["CablingApprovalAuthority"].ToString();
Session["CablingAdminUser"] = dtServerVars.Rows[0]["CablingAdminUser"].ToString();
Session["SharedInfoID"] = dtServerVars.Rows[0]["SharedInfoID"].ToString();
Session["SharedInfousername"] = dtServerVars.Rows[0]["SharedInfousername"].ToString();
Session["SharedInfopassword"] = dtServerVars.Rows[0]["SharedInfopassword"].ToString();
Session["SharedInfoname"] = dtServerVars.Rows[0]["SharedInfoname"].ToString();
Session["SharedInfoemail"] = dtServerVars.Rows[0]["SharedInfoemail"].ToString();
Session["SharedInfoICLlocation"] = dtServerVars.Rows[0]["SharedInfoID"].ToString();
Session["SharedInfoPhone"] = dtServerVars.Rows[0]["SharedInfoPhone"].ToString();
Session["SharedInfoSecLevel"] = dtServerVars.Rows[0]["SharedInfoSecLevel"].ToString();
Session["IMSUserID"] = dtServerVars.Rows[0]["IMSUserID"].ToString();
Session["IMSUserName"] = dtServerVars.Rows[0]["IMSUserName"].ToString();
Session["IMSIsAnonymous"] = dtServerVars.Rows[0]["IMSIsAnonymous"].ToString();
Session["IMSLastActivityDate"] = dtServerVars.Rows[0]["IMSLastActivityDate"].ToString();
Session["loggedin"] = "unknown";
```

would appreciate some guidance on this please...

Comment: What DO you get? A compiler error? A runtime error? If not, what are the session-variables filled with?

Comment: By the way: there a multiple things up for improvement in your code. But that is outside your question. I recommend you place your code at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and I will try to make your code a bit more sufficient.

Comment: No errors, the problem is that the session-variables appear empty (although im not 100% sure how what property to check)

Comment: Ill add my code to code review thanks Martin

Comment: If you set a brakepoint at the end of your session-set-code, then you can select a session value, for example Session["CablingUserID"]`. Then press SHIFT-F9 and you can see the contents. You can also open the Watch window and keep watch over all the values you put in there.

Comment: Martin as suggested: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/25677/building-session-variables-from-a-sql-stored-procedure-with-asp-net-c

Comment: I think that it was working then (good news for me), the problem was more about knowing where to get further information out of VS2010 whilst debugging. Thank You again Martin \o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future I answer this question by a combination of the comments above:

1. The code seems pretty straight forward. So was it not working.
2. There were not compile and runtime errors.
3. I asked for what results the programmer DID expect (a simply "it does not work" must always follow by "I expect it to work like this or that.")
4. The programmer said he just suspected that it was not working. So... he did not know for sure. He is talking about the "Locals" window in wich he can show local variables, but what about other variables?

To show other values during debugging of your application:

- Use your Watch-window. In there you can put all the variables you want to monitor, including, in this case, the Session-collection.
- Select a value and press SHIFT-F9, showing it in a QuickWatch window.